# How can I set default prefixes for routes?

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I'm trying to configure Spring-Cloud-Gateway.

The basic objective is adding routes for other services which consists

```
/some-api/**       -> http://some-api/**
/some-other-api/** -> http://some-other-api.com/**
```

Now the only working configuration is this.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: some-api
          uri: https://some-api.com
          predicates:
            - Path=/some-api/**
          filters:
            - StripPrefix=1 # REQUIRED?
        - id: some-other-api
          uri: https://some-other-api.com
          predicates:
            - Path=/some-other-api/**./g
          filters:
            - StripPrefix=1 # REQUIRED?
```

My question is are those `- StripPrefix=1` lines required?

When I commented out them, routes don't work.

The origin service gets prefixed request such as.

```
/some-api/swagger-ui.html -> http://some-api.com/some-api/swagger-ui.html
```

which should be

```
/some-api/swagger-ui.html -> http://some-api.com/swagger-ui.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes It is required.

`StripPrefixGatewayFilterFactory` strip parts of the request path before sending it downstream. Please check what `StringPrefixGatewayFilterFactory`.
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#_stripprefix_gatewayfilter_factory

If your request path is `/some-api/swagger-ui.html` and config is `StripPrefix=1`, StripPrefixGatewayFilterFactory will strip one part of the request path. In this case, the stripped part is `/some-api`.

To make it work the way you want, you have to strip one part of request path.